# How can i share objects between c++ application and python scripts

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, boost

I would like to extend a c++ application such that:

- C++ objects are available to python
- C++ application runs the python script
- python is able to manipulate C++ objects

I've been trying to use Boost.Python with the following test code:

This is Dog.hh

```
// Dog.hh
class dog
{
    int legs;
    int age;
public:
    void wag();
    void bark();
};
```

This is Dog.cc

```
 // Dog.cc
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "Dog.hh"

void
Dog::wag()
{
    std::cout << "wag, wag, wag" << std::endl;
}

void
Dog::bark()
{
    std::cout << "bark, woof" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libpydog)
{
    boost::python::class_<Dog>("Dog")
        .def("wag", &Dog::wag)
        .def("bark", &Dog::bark)
        ;
};
```

This is python-integration.cc The driver program

```
// python-integration.cc

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include "Dog.hh"

namespace python = boost::python;

void
run_it()
{
    std::string a_file = "py-test-dog.py";

    python::object main_module  = python::import("__main__");
    std::cout << "Imported main module" << std::endl;

    python::object global(main_module.attr("__dict__"));
    std::cout << "Created global environment" << std::endl;

    try
    {
        python::object ignored      = python::exec_file(
            a_file.c_str() , global, global );
        std::cout << "Executed script" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Running the script"
              << " with python interpreter"
              << std::endl;

    Py_Initialize();
    std::cout << "Initialized the python interpreter"
              << std::endl;

    if ( python::handle_exception(run_it) )
    {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
        {
            std::cout << "Python Error detected"
                      << std::endl;
            PyErr_Print();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "A C++ exception was thrown  for which "
                      << "there was no exception translator registered."
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, here is the cmake file im using to compile this:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
#   -*- cmake -*-


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(python_test CXX)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_DIR "build")

option(ENABLE_CLANG "build application with clang" ON)

if(ENABLE_CLANG)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER           "/usr/bin/clang++")
  set(CMAKE_AR                     "/usr/bin/llvm-ar")
  set(CMAKE_LINKER                 "/usr/bin/llvm-ld")
  set(CMAKE_NM                     "/usr/bin/llvm-nm")
  set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP                "/usr/bin/llvm-objdump")
  set(CMAKE_RANLIB                 "/usr/bin/llvm-ranlib")
else()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER           "/usr/bin/g++")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS       "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wextra")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-system-headers")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wold-style-cast")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Woverloaded-virtual")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wsign-promo")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Weffc++")



set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
  python
  REQUIRED
  )


include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 EXACT REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})


add_library(pydog SHARED
  Dog.cc
  )

target_link_libraries( pydog
  ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  )


add_executable(pytest
  Dog.cc
  python-integration.cc
  )

target_link_libraries(pytest
  ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  pydog
  )
##############################################################################
## Build Summary
message(STATUS "Directories:")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR          ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_BUILD_DIR           ${CMAKE_BUILD_DIR}")
message(STATUS "EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH    ${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH}")

message(STATUS "Compiler Options")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER   ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "CXX_COMPILER         ${CXX_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS      ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
message(STATUS "INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES  ${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")
```

Here is the python script im using to test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import libpydog

d = libpydog.Dog()
print("Wagging the dog")
d.wag()
print("Barking the dog")
d.bark()
```

Compilation completes without error.  If i run the python script i get:

```
./py-test-dog.py
Wagging the dog
wag, wag, wag
Barking the dog
bark, woof
```

*I know that is a lot of code for this post, I apologize I just wanted to be thorough.*

I want to see the same output when I run the c++ application, but I get a core dump.  I can post it here if it will help, but I'm hoping the clues are in the code above.

Adding the output as suggested:

```
~/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build $ ./pytest
Running the script with python interpreter
Initialized the python interpreter
Imported main module
Created global environment
*** Error in `/home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00000000014ffac0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f3760a84725]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7f3760a8cf4a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f3760a90abc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x103)[0x7f3760a7a313]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x1579ad)[0x7f3761c349ad]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0(_ZN5boost6python9exec_fileENS0_3strENS0_3api6objectES3_+0x4cb)[0x7f37618c7bcb]
/home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest(_Z6run_itv+0x176)[0x412e46]
/home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest(_ZN5boost6detail8function26void_function_ref_invoker0IPFvvEvE6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferE+0x1d)[0x41365d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0(_ZN5boost6python21handle_exception_implENS_9function0IvEE+0x73)[0x7f37618c2613]
/home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest(_ZN5boost6python16handle_exceptionIPFvvEEEbT_+0x88)[0x413348]
/home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest(main+0xa0)[0x413120]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f3760a2d830]
/home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest(_start+0x29)[0x40de29]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00418000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 6163807                            /home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest
00617000-00618000 r--p 00017000 fc:00 6163807                            /home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest
00618000-00619000 rw-p 00018000 fc:00 6163807                            /home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/pytest
01446000-0151c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f3758000000-7f3758021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3758021000-7f375c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f375f810000-7f37601cf000 r--p 00000000 fc:00 27925285                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f37601cf000-7f37601d1000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 19272214                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f37601d1000-7f37603d0000 ---p 00002000 fc:00 19272214                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f37603d0000-7f37603d1000 r--p 00001000 fc:00 19272214                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f37603d1000-7f37603d2000 rw-p 00002000 fc:00 19272214                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.23.so
7f37603d2000-7f37603d5000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 19272057                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f37603d5000-7f37605d4000 ---p 00003000 fc:00 19272057                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f37605d4000-7f37605d5000 r--p 00002000 fc:00 19272057                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f37605d5000-7f37605d6000 rw-p 00003000 fc:00 19272057                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f37605d6000-7f37605ef000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 19272224                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f37605ef000-7f37607ee000 ---p 00019000 fc:00 19272224                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f37607ee000-7f37607ef000 r--p 00018000 fc:00 19272224                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f37607ef000-7f37607f0000 rw-p 00019000 fc:00 19272224                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f37607f0000-7f3760808000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 19272179                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f3760808000-7f3760a07000 ---p 00018000 fc:00 19272179                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f3760a07000-7f3760a08000 r--p 00017000 fc:00 19272179                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f3760a08000-7f3760a09000 rw-p 00018000 fc:00 19272179                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f3760a09000-7f3760a0d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3760a0d000-7f3760bcd000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 19272033                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f3760bcd000-7f3760dcc000 ---p 001c0000 fc:00 19272033                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f3760dcc000-7f3760dd0000 r--p 001bf000 fc:00 19272033                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f3760dd0000-7f3760dd2000 rw-p 001c3000 fc:00 19272033                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f3760dd2000-7f3760dd6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3760dd6000-7f3760dec000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 19272071                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f3760dec000-7f3760feb000 ---p 00016000 fc:00 19272071                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f3760feb000-7f3760fec000 rw-p 00015000 fc:00 19272071                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f3760fec000-7f37610f4000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 19272103                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f37610f4000-7f37612f3000 ---p 00108000 fc:00 19272103                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f37612f3000-7f37612f4000 r--p 00107000 fc:00 19272103                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f37612f4000-7f37612f5000 rw-p 00108000 fc:00 19272103                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f37612f5000-7f3761467000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 27918734                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f3761467000-7f3761667000 ---p 00172000 fc:00 27918734                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f3761667000-7f3761671000 r--p 00172000 fc:00 27918734                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f3761671000-7f3761673000 rw-p 0017c000 fc:00 27918734                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f3761673000-7f3761677000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3761677000-7f376168f000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 6163410                    /home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/libpydog.so
7f376168f000-7f376188f000 ---p 00018000 fc:00 6163410                    /home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/libpydog.so
7f376188f000-7f3761890000 r--p 00018000 fc:00 6163410                    /home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/libpydog.so
7f3761890000-7f3761891000 rw-p 00019000 fc:00 6163410                    /home/aldrichtr/repos/cpp-projects/python-integration-test/build/libpydog.so
7f3761891000-7f37618da000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 27921547                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0
7f37618da000-7f3761ada000 ---p 00049000 fc:00 27921547                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0
7f3761ada000-7f3761adb000 r--p 00049000 fc:00 27921547                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0
7f3761adb000-7f3761add000 rw-p 0004a000 fc:00 27921547                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0
7f3761add000-7f3761dcf000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 27918842                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
7f3761dcf000-7f3761fcf000 ---p 002f2000 fc:00 27918842                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
7f3761fcf000-7f3761fd1000 r--p 002f2000 fc:00 27918842                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
7f3761fd1000-7f3762048000 rw-p 002f4000 fc:00 27918842                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
7f3762048000-7f376206b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f376206b000-7f3762091000 r-xp 00000000 fc:00 19272005                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f37620f5000-7f376226f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f376228d000-7f3762290000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f3762290000-7f3762291000 r--p 00025000 fc:00 19272005                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f3762291000-7f3762292000 rw-p 00026000 fc:00 19272005                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f3762292000-7f3762293000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff29d8e000-7fff29daf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff29dd2000-7fff29dd4000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff29dd4000-7fff29dd6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Well, well, clearly `exec_file()` breaks while... freeing the memory structure associated with the script file? Something, possibly out of our control, looks wrong here. Is this the minimal code with which you can reproduce the issue? Or are there funny things happening with the script file somewhere else in your actual program?

Comment: I have included all of the code, and i tried to make a minimal example using the dog class.

Comment: Okay, but stable glibc usually does not have the habit of double-freeing one of its internal structures when closing a file. Most probably heap corruption is happening somewhere, but I do not currently have the setup to try and reproduce this with the code you posted right now. Hopefully others can try. *(By the way the downvotes and close votes are not mine -- you did your best but the answer is not as evident as you wish it is, 's all :)*